# OS X stopped opening .jar files through Finder

Tags: macos, finder, java

Yosemite 10.10.5

I have a .jar file that I was able to execute by double-clicking it in Finder.  Today, if I try that, it won't open.  Sometimes something will appear briefly on screen but disappear before I can see what it is, and then nothing happens.  There are no error messages.  The Console records nothing.  The same thing happens whether I double-click the icon or use right-click > Open with > Jar Launcher (default) (15.0.0).

However, I find that I can open the file successfully, and with no error messages, using the terminal (`$ java -jar filename.jar`).

The only thing I've done since yesterday is install Anaconda and Git.  These may have added items to my PATH, but I don't think that could be the problem, since I can still open it from the command line.  Since discovering the problem, I've rebooted the machine, but the problem persists.

What happened, and how do I fix it?

Comment: it sounds like your file opened when you double-clicked it initially and then went to the background. Check the dock for the icon associated with the jar file and see if there is a dot under it.

Comment: Nothing changes about the dock when I attempt to open the file, and there are no icons already in the dock associated with it.  When I open through the terminal, the Java icon appears with a dot, and the program definitely isn't backgrounded.

Comment: If you right-click on your jar files and select 'get info' you should get a popup window.  Near the bottom of the window is the phrase 'Open with'.  What does it say in the box immediately below Open with. It should read 'Jar Launcher.app.

Comment: It does say "Jar Launcher (default) (15.0.0)"